# Linker replacing valid code with invalid code

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, linker, x86

So I've got a very strange and specific problem here. We're putting seemingly valid code into a linker, and then the linker is making some mistakes, like removing a valid ptr label and instead of replacing it with a value, it's putting in 0 instead. But not everywhere either. It starts at a pretty arbitrary point.

So, some background: we have an interpreted language that is converted into assembly by putting together hand-generated chunks of assembly (by an in-house compiler-like application) and adding in variables where required. This is a system that has been working for around 10 years if not longer, in pretty much it's current form, so the validity of this method is not currently in question. This assembly is assembled to an obj file using the Microsoft Assembler (ml.exe or MASM).

Then in a separate step, this obj file is linked using the Microsoft Incremental Linker together with some other libraries (static, and import libraries for dlls) to create an executable.

Following is a portion of the assembly (.asm) file that the assembler outputs when it creates the obj file in the first step:

```
call _c_rt_strcmp               
mov di, 1                   
mov ebp, esp                
cmp ax, 0                   
je sym2148                  
dec di                      
sym2148: mov [ebp+6], di        
add esp, 6                  
mov     ebx, dword ptr [_smfv1_ptr]     
add     ebx, 0bb49h     
pop ax
mov byte ptr [ebx],al
mov     ebx, dword ptr [_smfv1_ptr]     
add     ebx, 012656h        
push        ebx                     
mov eax, OFFSET sym2151
push eax
call _c_rt_strcmp               
mov di, 1                   
mov ebp, esp                
cmp ax, 0                   
je sym2152                  
dec di                      
sym2152: mov [ebp+6], di        
add esp, 6                  
mov     ebx, dword ptr [_smfv1_ptr]     
add     ebx, 0bb32h     
pop ax
mov byte ptr [ebx],al
mov     ebx, dword ptr [_smfv1_ptr]     
add     ebx, 012656h        
push        ebx                     
mov eax, OFFSET sym2155
push eax
call _c_rt_strcmp               
mov di, 1                   
mov ebp, esp                
cmp ax, 0                   
je sym2156                  
dec di                      
sym2156: mov [ebp+6], di        
add esp, 6                  
mov     ebx, dword ptr [_smfv1_ptr]     
add     ebx, 0bb4ah     
pop ax
mov byte ptr [ebx],al
mov     ebx, dword ptr [_smfv1_ptr]     
add     ebx, 0126bbh        
push        ebx                     
mov eax, OFFSET sym2159
push eax
call _c_rt_strcmp
```

As far as I can see, that is correct, and makes sense. I believe that code that generates this does a string compare and then stores a value based on the result of the string compare, and it's a section of 20-30 of them, so there are 10 or so more groups before the first bit I posted, and about 15-20 after the last bit I posted.

Following is the disassembled view of the crash location that Visual C++ 5.0 (old I know, but this is on a legacy system unfortunately) shows when the executable crashes:

```
004093D2   call        00629570
004093D7   mov         di,1
004093DB   mov         ebp,esp
004093DD   cmp         ax,0
004093E1   je          004093E5
004093E3   dec         di
004093E5   mov         word ptr [ebp+6],di
004093E9   add         esp,6
004093EC   mov         ebx,dword ptr ds:[64174Ch]
004093F2   add         ebx,0BB49h
004093F8   pop         ax
004093FA   mov         byte ptr [ebx],al
004093FC   mov         ebx,dword ptr ds:[64174Ch]
00409402   add         ebx,12656h
00409408   push        ebx
00409409   mov         eax,0
0040940E   push        eax
0040940F   call        00409414
00409414   mov         di,1
00409418   mov         ebp,esp
0040941A   cmp         ax,0
0040941E   je          00409422
00409420   dec         di
00409422   mov         word ptr [ebp+6],di
00409426   add         esp,6
00409429   mov         ebx,dword ptr ds:[0]
0040942F   add         ebx,0BB32h
00409435   pop         ax
00409437   mov         byte ptr [ebx],al
00409439   mov         ebx,dword ptr ds:[0]
0040943F   add         ebx,12656h
00409445   push        ebx
00409446   mov         eax,0
0040944B   push        eax
0040944C   call        00409451
00409451   mov         di,1
00409455   mov         ebp,esp
00409457   cmp         ax,0
0040945B   je          0040945F
0040945D   dec         di
0040945F   mov         word ptr [ebp+6],di
00409463   add         esp,6
00409466   mov         ebx,dword ptr ds:[0]
0040946C   add         ebx,0BB4Ah
00409472   pop         ax
00409474   mov         byte ptr [ebx],al
00409476   mov         ebx,dword ptr ds:[0]
0040947C   add         ebx,126BBh
00409482   push        ebx
00409483   mov         eax,0
00409488   push        eax
00409489   call        0040948E
```

The actual crash location is 0x00409429.

The two bits of code match, as in they are the same section of code, except the first from the .asm file is what is going into the linker, and the second one is that has come out of the linker.

From what I can see, it's crashing at that location because it's attempting to de-reference an address of 0, right? So of course that's going to fail. Also, if you take a look at the different function calls at 0x004093D2, 0x0040940F, 0x0040944C and 0x00409489, only the first one is valid, the others are simply doing a function call to the line directly after them! And this broken code continues on for the next 15-20 similar segments of code that is defined in that file.

If you look at the corresponding lines for the function calls and the bad pointers in both sections, you will see that in the .asm file everything appears to be correct, but somehow the linker just breaks it all when it compiles the exe, and in a very specific spot, as there are similar chunks of code previous in the file which are constructed correctly.

We do get some linker warnings of the form: "LINK : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol "_smfv1_ptr" imported". But we were getting those same warnings even when it was working.

The assembler used was ml.exe version 6.11, and the linker was link.exe version 5.10.7303 which were both the version from Visual C++ 5.0. Since the assembled code seems to be right, I'm going to be trying the linker from Visual Studio 2005, 2008 and 2010 and see if anything changes.

I can't really imagine what could create this kind of error, and I thought maybe it was symbols getting messed up, but there are jumps to locations (for small 'if' statements) which are stored as symbols which still work fine after they get through the linker.

Is it possible that a symbol table or something similar is getting overloaded inside the linker, and it's just reverting to bad or default values?

Comment: I'd normally recommend posting to Connect but there's no point at all with such old tools.  Focus on getting rid of the linker warning.  And updating your tools.

Comment: Wow, Visual C++ 5.0? I thought everyone had at least updated to Visual C++ 6... The time you spent debugging this problem and writing this question could have been better spent making your code compile with a recent version of the compiler, one without so many bugs.

Comment: Guys, I KNOW it's old, and I wish it wasn't so. Upgrading is a possibility, but only if it will solve the problem, and I just tested using the linker from Visual Studio 2005, 2008 and 2010, and I ended up with the same executable with the exact same problems.

The assembler is still the older version because the assembly generated appears to be exactly the same, ie. still correct.

Comment: What changed to make it stop working?  Since it appears to link part of the file correctly have you tried breaking the .obj into multiple .obj files?

Answer (score 1):

Call to the following address is a clear sign of unresolved symbol reference (it makes sense if you notice that all calls in .obj files are emitted as E8 00 00 00 00). You have zeroes for some data references as well (sym2151, some references to _smfv1_ptr, sym2159). What's strange is that the first call to _c_rt_strcmp did get resolved. I would suggest turning on all warning/debugging/verbose switches that you can find, and generating all kinds of listing and map files. Maybe something will jump out.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the end result seems to be that it is a bug with the Visual C++ version of the masm assembler "ml.exe" (big surprise, huh?)

So, moving to the versions of masm and link that were provided in Visual Studio 2005 seems to be the best solution for us.

Thanks for your help guys :)